# Windows Server 2012 R2 Powershell IP Interfaces Compartments

Tags: networking, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

If I run `Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -IncludeAllCompartments`, I get one Interface back.

There are only 2 Compartments I checked this via `@(Get-NetCompartment).Count`.
The Compartment IDs are 1 and 2. This information is also printed by `Get-NetCompartment`.

But If I run Get-NetIPInterface -CompartmetId 2 I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -CompartmentId 1
Get-NetIPInterface : No matching MSFT_NetIPInterface objects found by CIM query for instances of the
ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPInterface class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPInterface  WHERE
((InterfaceIndex = 29)) AND ((CompartmentId = 1)). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -CompartmentId 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPInterface:String) [Get-NetIPInterface], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-NetIPInterface
```

or this

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -CompartmentId 2
Get-NetIPInterface : No matching MSFT_NetIPInterface objects found by CIM query for instances of the
ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPInterface class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPInterface  WHERE
((InterfaceIndex = 29)) AND ((CompartmentId = 2)). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -CompartmentId 2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPInterface:String) [Get-NetIPInterface], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-NetIPInterface

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Why do I get this error?
If the Interface is not in Compartment 1 and not in Compartment 2, where it is?

More Information:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>  Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -IncludeAllCompartments

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
29      NIC_INTERN_CONTOSO              IPv4                  1500               5 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetCompartment


CompartmentId          : 1
CompartmentDescription : Default Compartment
CompartmentGuid        : !SOME NUMBERS!

CompartmentId          : 2
CompartmentDescription : COMPARTMENT2
CompartmentGuid        : !SOME NUMBERS"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this to find out what CompartmentId it is in:

```
Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 29 -IncludeAllCompartments | ForEach-Object { "$($_.InterfaceAlias) - $($_.CompartmentId)" }
```

Use that to check that it actually is in one of those compartments.